# Как сравнить строки игнорируя диакритические знаки?

Tags: javascript, строки, сравнение

Пользователь вводит строку **Arke**.
Мне же надо её сравнить со строкой **Arkè**, чтобы они были равны.

слово **Arkè** с диакритическим знаком лишь как пример. нужно решение, которое будет работать с подобными диакритическими знаками.

Comment: Используйте [нормализацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, пример кода в студию, пожалуйста

Comment: Как-то вслепую такое делать опасно. Может быть, что Arke и Arkè - это совсем разные слова и сравнивать их некорректно. Я все же думаю, что у вас есть определенный язык, в котором это надо делать, а не для любого языка, в котором есть такие знаки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сперва делаем [нормализацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) - это преобразует символ один `è` в два символа: `e` и диакритический знак.

Затем удаляем диакритические знаки. Они входят в диапазон юникода U+0300 - U+036F. Дополнительно [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511463/5045688).

После чего сравниваем полученные значения.

```js
const name1 = 'Arke';
const name2 = 'Arkè';

console.log(name1 + ' ' + name2); // output: "Arke, Arkè"
console.log(name1 === name2); // output: false

const name1N = name1.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
const name2N = name2.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");

console.log(name1N + ' ' + name2N); //  output: "Arke, Arke"
console.log(name1N === name2N); //  output: true
```

Comment: вот это просто божественно. низкий Вам поклон

Answer (score 3):

как один из вариантов (что первое пришло в голову), заводить словарь, сравнивать ключ, а значением это ключа будет тоже самое слово, только с диакритическими знаками

```js
const input = 'Arke'

const obj = {
  'Arke': 'Arkè'
};

[...Object.keys(obj)].forEach(key => {
  if (key.toLowerCase() === input.toLowerCase()) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
  }
})
```

либо другой вариант, [источник](http://web.archive.org/web/20120918093154/http://lehelk.com/2011/05/06/script-to-remove-diacritics/)

```js
var defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap = [{
    'base': 'A',
    'letters': /[\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'AA',
    'letters': /[\uA732]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'AE',
    'letters': /[\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'AO',
    'letters': /[\uA734]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'AU',
    'letters': /[\uA736]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'AV',
    'letters': /[\uA738\uA73A]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'AY',
    'letters': /[\uA73C]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'B',
    'letters': /[\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'C',
    'letters': /[\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'D',
    'letters': /[\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'DZ',
    'letters': /[\u01F1\u01C4]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'Dz',
    'letters': /[\u01F2\u01C5]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'E',
    'letters': /[\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'F',
    'letters': /[\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'G',
    'letters': /[\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'H',
    'letters': /[\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'I',
    'letters': /[\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'J',
    'letters': /[\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'K',
    'letters': /[\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'L',
    'letters': /[\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'LJ',
    'letters': /[\u01C7]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'Lj',
    'letters': /[\u01C8]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'M',
    'letters': /[\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'N',
    'letters': /[\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'NJ',
    'letters': /[\u01CA]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'Nj',
    'letters': /[\u01CB]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'O',
    'letters': /[\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'OI',
    'letters': /[\u01A2]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'OO',
    'letters': /[\uA74E]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'OU',
    'letters': /[\u0222]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'P',
    'letters': /[\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'Q',
    'letters': /[\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'R',
    'letters': /[\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'S',
    'letters': /[\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'T',
    'letters': /[\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'TZ',
    'letters': /[\uA728]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'U',
    'letters': /[\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'V',
    'letters': /[\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'VY',
    'letters': /[\uA760]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'W',
    'letters': /[\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'X',
    'letters': /[\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'Y',
    'letters': /[\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'Z',
    'letters': /[\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'a',
    'letters': /[\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'aa',
    'letters': /[\uA733]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'ae',
    'letters': /[\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'ao',
    'letters': /[\uA735]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'au',
    'letters': /[\uA737]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'av',
    'letters': /[\uA739\uA73B]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'ay',
    'letters': /[\uA73D]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'b',
    'letters': /[\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'c',
    'letters': /[\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'd',
    'letters': /[\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'dz',
    'letters': /[\u01F3\u01C6]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'e',
    'letters': /[\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'f',
    'letters': /[\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'g',
    'letters': /[\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'h',
    'letters': /[\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'hv',
    'letters': /[\u0195]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'i',
    'letters': /[\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'j',
    'letters': /[\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'k',
    'letters': /[\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'l',
    'letters': /[\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'lj',
    'letters': /[\u01C9]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'm',
    'letters': /[\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'n',
    'letters': /[\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'nj',
    'letters': /[\u01CC]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'o',
    'letters': /[\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'oi',
    'letters': /[\u01A3]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'ou',
    'letters': /[\u0223]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'oo',
    'letters': /[\uA74F]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'p',
    'letters': /[\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'q',
    'letters': /[\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'r',
    'letters': /[\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 's',
    'letters': /[\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 't',
    'letters': /[\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'tz',
    'letters': /[\uA729]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'u',
    'letters': /[\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'v',
    'letters': /[\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'vy',
    'letters': /[\uA761]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'w',
    'letters': /[\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'x',
    'letters': /[\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'y',
    'letters': /[\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF]/g
  },
  {
    'base': 'z',
    'letters': /[\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763]/g
  }
];
var changes;

function removeDiacritics(str) {
  if (!changes) {
    changes = defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < changes.length; i++) {
    str = str.replace(changes[i].letters, changes[i].base);
  }
  return str;
}

const input = 'Arke';

if (input.toLowerCase() === removeDiacritics('Arkè').toLowerCase()) {
  console.log(true);
}
```

Comment: к сожалению, это не подойдет, так как в вопросе слово **Arkè** лишь как пример. дело в том, что слово для сравнения (с диакритическим знаком) будет непредсказуемое и кто знает какой там еще диакритический знак будет..

Comment: @Август, т.е. вы хотите сравнивать с чем-то, но не знаете с чем?

Comment: конечно) в том и суть вопроса